# To implement 'for' loop in simulink model

Tags: matlab, image-processing, simulink

I am trying to create model using simulink.
my question is whether looping like, 'for','while','do while' loops can be modelled in simulink?
My code part is attached here:

```
for n=1:iter_outer
   if mod(n,2)==0
    pause(0.001);
    imagesc(Img,[0, 255]); colormap(gray); axis off; axis equal;
    hold on;
    contour(u,[0 0],'r');
    iterNum=[num2str(n), ' iterations'];
    title(iterNum);
    hold off;
end;end;
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you are trying to implement, but because of the `pause(0.001)` I think you should use a subsystem which is triggered every 0.001s or a model with a sample time of 0.001

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`For Iterator` subsystem](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/foriteratorsubsystem.html) to implement `for loops. Alternatively, you can use a [MATLAB Function](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html) block to implement your MATLAB code.